# CNN accuracy doesn't change through multiple epochs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a CNN which differentiates b/w pictures of eyes with/without symptoms of diabetic retinopathy. When I tried to run my model, the accuracy didn't improve at all. I tried using different learning rates, but it hasn't worked. Since this is my first time making a CNN, I think I might have made a mistake elsewhere. If you see the problems within my code, please let me know, I would really appreciate the help.

```
Train on 980 samples, validate on 327 samples
Epoch 1/5
980/980 [==============================] - 777s 792ms/step - loss: 8.1986 - accuracy: 0.4653 - val_loss: 8.8154 - val_accuracy: 0.4251
Epoch 2/5
980/980 [==============================] - 666s 679ms/step - loss: 8.1986 - accuracy: 0.4653 - val_loss: 8.8154 - val_accuracy: 0.4251
Epoch 3/5
980/980 [==============================] - 672s 686ms/step - loss: 8.1986 - accuracy: 0.4653 - val_loss: 8.8154 - val_accuracy: 0.4251
```

Here is my code:

```
DATADIR = "C:\\Users.."
CATEGORIES = ["nosymptoms", "symptoms"]
training_data = []
IMG_SIZE = 512
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) #brings us to folder with categories
    class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) #img resized and becomes array
        training_data.append([new_array, class_num]) #classification is appended to image
```

```
import random
random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])#0 is the image array, 1 is the label
X = [] #features set
y = [] #labels
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)#shape of features (-1 means any), img size, 1 (b/c it is a grayscale) 
#Save data
import pickle
pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

X = X/255.0
```

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3),input_shape=(X.shape[1:]),activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

from keras.optimizers import SGD
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 16, epochs = 5, validation_split=.25)
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a few things. One, run 15 epochs and post the output instead of 3 epoches. Second can you post what X and y looks like?

Comment: This happens because you use a softmax with one neuron, which produces a constant output, there are hundreds of questions here with the same issue. Just change the activation to sigmoid.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have 2 classes ,change your last layer to 2 neurons

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3),input_shape=(X.shape[1:]),activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

from keras.optimizers import SGD
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 16, epochs = 5, validation_split=.25)
```

Comment: For binary labels, you can use 1 output for 0 or 1 or you can use 2 for one-hot 01 and 10 and this depends on your implementation. this is not the problem. also for your answer, you have to use `categorical_crossentropy` for `loss`